# Merging columns based on the specific value

Tags: microsoft-excel, merge

I am working on an excel sheet where i need to merge cells bases on vehicle number. If there is same vehicle number in two or more consicutive cells then i need to merge the cells to right to the vehicle number. I have a huge file which contains 200 something vehicle numbers. So merging cells based on each vehicle is a time consuming task. Is there any way to simplify this. I have attached a screenshot of my excel sheet.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzA6d.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I would like to suggest you the VBA code to achieve your goal, since it's the best and easiest possible method to apply.*

You can use the below written VBA code to Merge adjacent cells in Right Column, if the values Left to them are duplicate.

*Check the Screen Shot:*

[image]

```
Sub MergeSameCell()

Dim Rng As Range, xCell As Range
Dim xRows As Integer
xTitleId = "Merge Cells In Excel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
xRows = WorkRng.Rows.Count
For Each Rng In WorkRng.Columns
    For i = 1 To xRows - 1
        For j = i + 1 To xRows
            If Rng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Rng.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 2), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 2)).Merge
        WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 3), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 3)).Merge
        WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 4), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 4)).Merge
        i = j - 1

    Next
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**How to use the Code:**

- Hold down the ALT + F11 keys, and it opens the Microsoft Visual Basic
  for Applications window.
- Click Insert then Module, and paste the Code.
- Run the Macro.
- When Input box appear select the Data range where Duplicate values
  are Available.
- Finish with ok.

*You get the job done.*

Comment: Glad to hear from you @Sans, & happy to help you,, keep asking :-)